# Make URL Request from Servlet and retain Header information

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, urlconnection

I need to make a request from a servlet but I also need to retain all the header information.  That is in the request object.

For example, I if I do something like the following from the doGet method, is there a simple way to just pass that information to the URL Connection object?

```
URL url = new URL();
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
uc.setDoOutput(true);
uc.setDoInput(true);
uc.setUseCaches(false);

uc.setRequestProperty("Content-type",
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(uc.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(strInEnc);
dos.flush();
dos.close();

InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
int chr = in.read();
while (chr != -1) {
taResults.append(String.valueOf((char) chr));
chr = in.read();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`addRequestProperty`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#addRequestProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method of `URLConnection`.

```
Enumeration<?> names = req.getHeaderNames();
while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
  String key = (String) names.nextElement();
  Enumeration<?> values = req.getHeaders(key);
  while (values.hasMoreElements()) {
    uc.addRequestProperty(key, (String) values.nextElement());
  }
}
```

You'll have a similar set of loops if you use HttpClient, unless it has built-in support for pass-through of a `ServletRequest`. (And if it doesn't, why bother with a huge set of additional dependencies, and non-standard API?)

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate all the headers with the request.getHeaderNames() method. However, I recommend to use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) instead of UrlConnection to make the request.

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96360/writing-post-data-from-one-java-servlet-to-another